# Is there a fast parallel "for" loop in Perl 6?

Tags: concurrency, raku

Given some code which does a bit of math/casting for each number from 1 to 500000, we have options:

1. Simple for loop: `for ^500000 -> $i { my $result = ($i ** 2).Str; }`. In my unscientific benchmark, this takes 2.8 seconds.
2. The most canonical parallel version does each bit of work in a `Promise`, then waits for the result. `await do for ^500000 -> $i { start { my $result = ($i ** 2).Str; } }` takes 19 seconds. This is slow! Creating a new promise must have too much overhead to be worthwhile for such a simple computation.
3. Using a parallel `map` operation is fairly fast. At 2.0 seconds, the operation seems barely slow enough to take advantage of parallelization: `(^500000).race.map: -> $i { my $result = ($i ** 2).Str; }`

The third option seems best. Unfortunately, it reads like a hack. We should not be writing `map` code for iteration in sink context, because others that read "map" in the source may assume the purpose is to build a list, which isn't our intent at all. It's poor communication to use `map` this way.

Is there any canonical fast way to use Perl 6's built in concurrency? A hyper operator would be perfect if it could accept a block instead of only functions:

```
(^500000)».(-> $i { my $result = ($i ** 2).Str; }) # No such method 'CALL-ME' for invocant of type 'Int'
```

Comment: Shouldn't the loop run in zero time as it has no effects?

Comment: @BarneySchmale You've just illustrated why I don't like using `map` in place of `for`. In Perl 6, `map` isn't lazy, so it works like `for`. (Specifically, it works like `do for`.) `map` will execute for all list elements, even if the result isn't used. But choosing `map` instead of `for` communicates that the goal is to build a list, and in this case it's not true.

Comment: @piojo `map` is almost always lazy. Try `say [1..Inf].map(*+100)[1..10]`. Aiui... By default, `for` is A) like a `map` that's eager rather than lazy and B) a control flow statement rather than an expression. A `do` turns a statement into an expression by running the code that follows it and returning the list of values generated by the code. (Without it, a `for` will return no values at all.)

Comment: @raiph If you run `perl6 -e "<a b c>.map: &say"`, you'll see that `map` is eager in simple cases. It's good design if `map` becomes lazy when its input is lazy, but I would be surprised if that were the majority of code. It seems like input is lazy when it comes from I/O methods, but otherwise it will usually be eager.

Comment: @piojo Try `perl6 -e "(<a b c>.map: &say)[1]"` and note how it outputs two lines. That's because P6 lists are generally lazy. The eager *context* you supplied trumps `map`'s lazy nature.

Comment: @raiph Thanks, I stand corrected. (All the more reason not to ever use `map` as a substitute for `for`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use for with a hyper or race operation, you have to spell it `hyper for @blah.hyper(:batch(10_000))` or `race for @blah.race(:batch(10_000))`. Or without parameters: `hyper for @blah`, `race for @blah`.

This was decided because you might have code like `for some-operation() { some-non-threadsafe-code }` where `some-operation` is part of a library or something. Now you cannot tell any more if the for loop can have thread-unsafe code in it or not, and even if you know the library doesn't return a `HyperSeq` at that point in time, what if the library author comes up with this *great idea* to make `some-operation` faster by hypering it?

That's why a signifier for "it's safe to run this for loop in parallel" is required right where the code is, not only where the sequence gets created.

Comment: Did you thinko the doubled use of `hyper` in `hyper for @foo.hyper` (and likewise with `race`)? That isn't what jnthn was saying on channel and in his Rakudo commits through late October. If you didn't thinko this then is there somewhere I could read about that other than your answer here? TIA.

Comment: you're right. you don't have to put it in there if you're just iterating over a list or something. i edited it to have a batch setting in there so you can see how to get options in there with a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

On my PC, this is a bit (~15%) faster than the naive loop:

```
(^500_000).hyper(batch => 100_000).map(-> $i { my $result = ($i ** 2).Str; })
```

Since the computation inside the loop is really fast, typically the cost of parallelization and synchronization dwarfs any gains you get from it. The only remedy is a large batch size.

Update: with a batch size of 200_000 I get slightly better results (another few percent faster).

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I noticed a real world script is 15% slower with promises than with `.hyper.map`, but still far faster than the non-parallel version. So promises aren't only a slowdown when you're using them in the wrong situation.

Comment: May I infer from this answer that there's no actual imperative parallel loop of any type?: `for @a.hyper -> $element { ... }`